# Enabled Notification Access without user interaction

Tags: android, adb, android-notifications

I have a rooted phone and i want to assign my application to access notifications without user interaction like open settings and toggle from there but not find any proper way(Not programatically OR visa ADB command).
I have actually seen an old post where someone share a [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/4goz99/how_to_replace_some_secure_settings_actions_with/?st=jdt7yfi0&sh=0522b1d7):

So i have tried like this:

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_notification_listeners %nlisteners:mypackageName/com.company.app.service.CallNotificationListener
```

Command run without any error on shell but when i open Notification Access from phone settings, my application still not mark as a notification receiver. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 9 Your command is not working anymore. What worked for me was to use :

```
adb shell cmd notification allow_listener com.mypackage.app/com.mypackage.app.mylistener
```

It doesn't need root permission even in my case.